# Storing data in laravel happens once

Tags: php, laravel, saving-data

Hi there best colleagues i've the following strange issue when i want to store data in my database but accomplish this task just once, when i want to store another data i get the following problem:
"Whoops something went wrong".

i've the following code in my controller

```
public function store()
    {
        $user = new User();
        $user->username = Input::get('username');
        $user->save();

        return Response::json(array(
            'error' => false,
            'succes' => $user->toArray()),
            200
        );
    }
```

and this is my routes.php

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v1'), function() {
    Route::resource('users', 'UserController',
        array('except' => array('create', 'edit')));
});
```

I'm trying to post trough Postmen extension in Chrome and when i request a post to my uri:

http://www.bla.com/testLaravel/api/v1/users
(bla.com = localhost)

it just stores once my data and after that i get an error , i seriously can't figure out what the problem is. It would be great if someone can help me with it.

tnx

Comment: Gee, if only you told us **what the error you get is**? Consult your logs.

Comment: I only get "Whoops something went wrong"

Comment: Fixed the issue it was in the response